# Radio button: input was not found in the haystack?

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

Whenever I submit the form I get this message:

`The input was not found in the haystack.`

This is for the `shipping-method` element (radio button). Can't figure out what it means, the POST data for that element is not null.

```
public function getInputFilter()
{
    if (!$this->inputFilter) {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

        // Some other basic filters

        $inputFilter->add(array(
                'name' => 'shipping-method',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim')
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'max' => 20,
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Db\RecordExists',
                        'options' => array(
                            'table' => 'shipping',
                            'field' => 'shipping_method',
                            'adapter' => $this->dbAdapter
                        )
                    ),
                ),
        ));

        $inputFilter->get('shipping-address-2')->setRequired(false);
        $inputFilter->get('shipping-address-3')->setRequired(false);

        $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
    }

    return $this->inputFilter;
}
```

I only keep finding solutions for `<select>`.

Here's the sample POST data:

```
object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)#143 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private] => array(9) {
    ["shipping-name"] => string(4) "TEST"
    ["shipping-address-1"] => string(4) "test"
    ["shipping-address-2"] => string(0) ""
    ["shipping-address-3"] => string(0) ""
    ["shipping-city"] => string(4) "TEST"
    ["shipping-state"] => string(4) "TEST"
    ["shipping-country"] => string(4) "TEST"
    ["shipping-method"] => string(6) "Ground"
    ["submit-cart-shipping"] => string(0) ""
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:
form.phtml**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->formRow($form->get('shipping-method')); ?>
    <?= $this->formRadio($form->get('shipping-method')
            ->setValueOptions(array(
                'Ground' => 'Ground',
                'Expedited' => 'Expedited'))
            ->setDisableInArrayValidator(true)); ?>
</div>
```

**ShippingForm.php**

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'shipping-method',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Shipping Method',
            'label_attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'lbl-shipping-method'
            ),
        )
    ));
```

Comment: Can we see your form element code please?

Comment: @Garry I updated my question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with when you use the `setValueOptions()` and the `setDisableInArrayValidator()`. You should do this earlier within your code as it is never set before validating your form and so the inputfilter still contain the defaults as the `InArray` validator. As after validation, which checks the inputfilter, you set different options for the shipping_methods.

You should move the `setValueOptions()` and the `setDisableInArrayValidator()` before the `$form->isValid()`. Either by setting the right options within the form itsself or doing this in the controller. Best way is to keep all of the options in one place and doing it inside the form class.

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'shipping-method',
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
    'options' => [
        'value_options' => [
            'Ground'    => 'Ground',
            'Expedited' => 'Expedited'
        ],
        'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
        'label' => 'Shipping Method',
        'label_attributes' => [
            'class' => 'lbl-shipping-method',
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Another small detail you might want to change is setting the value options. They are now hardcoded but your inputfilter is checking against database records whether they exist or not. Populate the value options with the database records. If the code still contains old methods but the database has a few new ones, they are not in sync.

```
class ShippingForm extends Form
{
    private $dbAdapter;

    public function __construct(AdapterInterface $dbAdapter, $name = 'shipping-form', $options = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $options)
        // inject the databaseAdapter into your form
        $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    }

    public function init()
    {
        // adding form elements to the form
        // we use the init method to add form elements as from this point
        // we also have access to custom form elements which the constructor doesn't

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'shipping-method',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
            'options' => [
                'value_options' => $this->getDbValueOptions(),
                'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
                'label' => 'Shipping Method',
                'label_attributes' => [
                    'class' => 'lbl-shipping-method',
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }

    private function getDbValueOptions()
    {
        $statement = $this->dbAdapter->query('SELECT shipping_method FROM shipping');
        $rows = $statement->execute();

        $valueOptions = [];

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $valueOptions[$row['shipping_method']] = $row['shipping_method'];
        }

        return $valueOptions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this happen yesterday.

The select and multi select ZF2+ elements have a built in in_array validator.

Remember filters occur before validators.

You may be doing too much here -- it is very rare to need to filter or add validators ot select and multi select form elements in ZF2 forms.  The built in element validator is robust, ZF does a lot of work for us.

Try removing both filter and validator for the element, such as:

```
$inputFilter->add(array(
            'name' => 'shipping-method',
            'required' => true,
    ));
```

There is another edge case that I have seen: changing the select element's valueOptions somewhere in the controller (or view) resulting in different valueOptions used in view vs form validation (in our case it was replacing the element with a new one before validation).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the fact you are adding your value options after the InArray validator has been set, hence the validator has no haystack.

Try this

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'shipping-method',
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Shipping Method',
        'label_attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'lbl-shipping-method'
        ),
        'value_options' => array(
            'Ground' => 'Ground',
            'Expedited' => 'Expedited'
        ),
        'disable_inarray_validator' => TRUE,
    )
));
```

and remove setValueOptions and setDisableInArrayValidator from your view.

Hope this works.